# Why is the cookie service returning the wrong value?

Tags: angular, cookies, service

I'm using Angular 6 to set up some API calls, and using ngx cookieService to access and store cookies. I want to take the access token I get from my API and use it as a header when sending get requests in another service. Here is the function in my login service:

```
getData()  {
    return this.http.post(this.base_URL + "web_app/login/", JSON.stringify(this.login))   

  .subscribe(response=>{    
     this.access_token = response['access_token'];
     console.log("received token " + this.access_token)
     this.cookieService.set( 'access_token', this.access_token );
     this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('access_token');
     console.log("set cookie value" + this.cookieValue);

    } }
```

Here is the other service:

```
farmAccess(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('access_token');
    headers.append('access_token', this.cookieValue);
    console.log("retrieved cookie value" + this.cookieValue);
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + 'web_app/farm_access/', {headers})
.subscribe(
res => console.log(res),
         // msg => console.error(`Error: ${msg.status} ${msg.statusText}`
        )
   };
```

I'm storing the access token as a cookie, and want to access it in the farmAccess service. However, this isn't working. Comparing the two cookies, this is what comes on the console:

[image: cookie comparison]

This is where I call functions:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.data = this.login.getData();
this.farmAccessdata = this.getFarmAccess.farmAccess();
```

}

I checked the cookies in the console, and it's displaying the correct value for access_token. So why is the farmAccess service pulling the wrong value? Thank you for your help!

Edit: it looks like the functions are running out of order. How do I get them to run in the order I want?

Comment: Why not just use sessionStorage or localStorage?? would eliminate the use of the cookie service, this.cookie.service would become `this.localStorage.set( 'access_token', this.access_token );`

Comment: As per your screen shot , it seems that farmAccess() is getting called before getData() - which stores new token. because of this farmAccess() is getting old token from cookie.

Comment: @HirenShah I'm calling getData() before farmAccess() though? I've updated my post to show this

Comment: @may I see the problem here, as login.getdata() makes an API call , 
    this.farmAccessdata = this.getFarmAccess.farmAccess(); 
statement get executed before the API response  is actually received.

Comment: I was stuck with the same problems. for some reason my older cookie value was get from somewhere like a ghost. It probably has to do something with 'smart' caching of the browser, because when I used the debug console to get the value it was still the newest one. the best way is to execute the code realtime instead of using a service. I found a solution and I am now working with interceptors. This will allow you to inject additional information during (http)request and (http)response time. And unlike services, injectors seems to be executed everytime instead of some smart caching. see this lin

Answer (score 0):

Change your login service function as follows

```
getData()  {
    return this.http.post(this.base_URL + "web_app/login/", JSON.stringify(this.login));

}
```

And component ngOnInit Method as bellow:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = this.login.getData().subscribe(response =>{

        // Set the token & cookie from the component. Changes access_token ==> login.access_token
        // You may also need to inject cookieService in component as well
        this.login.access_token = response['access_token']; 

        console.log("received token " + this.login.access_token)
        this.cookieService.set( 'access_token', this.login.access_token );
        this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('access_token');
        console.log("set cookie value" + this.cookieValue);

        // Move this call in subscribe method
        this.farmAccessdata = this.getFarmAccess.farmAccess();
    });

}
```